# Angular 6 integrate multiple themes with lazy loading

Tags: angular-material, angular6, single-page-application

In my Angular 6 SPA, I want to use multiple themes for different modules of my project.

Is it possible to do so? If yes how? An example will be very helpful.

Also, I want to achieve this using lazy loading.